# Downloading a PDF from email: "/" gets replaced

Tags: email, pdf, filenames

First of all, this is my first time using super user. I'm pretty sure that SO isn't the right place to ask this, and this isn't limited to just Mac, as it's with email, so I decided to ask here. If this needs to be migrated, please let me know.

When emailing a file, I noticed that every slash got replaced. I'm on gmail, and when attaching a file named `1/2.pdf`, Gmail shows me `1:2.pdf`[image]

After emailing myself to test, and downloading the pdf for myself, it got downloaded as [image]
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two *slightly* different issues, but neither of them is actually email-related.

---

> When emailing a file, I noticed that every slash got replaced. I'm on gmail, and when attaching a file named `1/2.pdf`, Gmail shows me `1:2.pdf`[image]

That's a macOS (OS X) quirk.

Normally, the slash `/` is the *path separator* in OS X (and other operating systems) and therefore not possible to use in file names. If you literally tried to create a file named `1/2.pdf`, that would actually be interpreted as "file `2.pdf` inside folder `1`." This also applies to Linux, Windows, Android, and just about everything else.

But original MacOS (before OS X) used `:` as the path separator, instead of slash – which *was* allowed in names then. This still affects old HFS+ formatted disks (which might have filenames with slashes in them) as well as programs built using older toolkits.

So Finder still lets you use `/` in names, but under the hood it is translated to `:` when crossing over to the Unix-based core of macOS. (And translated *again* to `/` if it goes to a HFS+ disk…)

For example, using the `ls` command in Terminal you would see that your file is actually `/Users/Ryan/1:2.pdf` (as opposed to `/Users/Ryan/1/2.pdf`). And various apps might see the same file as either `1:2.pdf` or `1/2.pdf` depending on how they were written.

Related posts:

- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031114045400715
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13298479
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/425171

---

> After emailing myself to test, and downloading the pdf for myself, it got downloaded as [image]

That's done deliberately by browsers on Windows, because *neither* `/` nor `:` are allowed in file names on Windows – they both work as separators for different things.

In Windows, slash `/` is used as an alternate path separator alongside the usual backslash `\` – for example, the path `C:\Users\Ryan` can be written as `C:/Users/Ryan` or `C:\Users/Ryan`.

Meanwhile the colon `:` is used both as the drive-letter indicator, and as the *alternate stream* separator (the latter is like "xattrs" and "resource forks" on macOS).

If a program actually tried to create a file named `1:2.pdf`, Windows would interpret it as "file `2.pdf` on disk `1:`" (yes, Windows drive "letters" can also be numbers); whereas if the program used `Downloads/1:2.pdf`, that would be interpreted as "directory `Downloads`, file name `1`, alternate stream `2.pdf`".

So browsers on Windows have to replace both such characters (and a few more, like `?` or `*` or `>`) whenever downloading files.

Related:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions

Comment: "That's done deliberately by browsers on Windows", but I'm on a mac? Great start so far though

Comment: @Ryan: Ah, the 2nd image looked extremely like the Windows layout – Adobe Reader icon, font, and all. Still – if you're using e.g. Chrome or Firefox, they're very likely to just share the same "lowest common denominator" filtering code across all platforms they run on; for example, I also get such characters replaced with `_` even though I'm on Linux where they'd be allowed. (Safari is another topic but even it used to run on Windows for a time...)